# Use "Stream-like" Input to C++ function

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream

I am aware that one can use preprocessor macros to create a function that accepts a "stream-like" input. In order to clarify what I mean by "stream-like" input, let me give you an example (The input to *LOGGER* is "stream-like"):

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define LOGGER(streamText) {   \
    std::ostringstream buffer; \
    buffer << streamText;      \
    /* Some processing */      \
    std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl; \
}

int main(){
    LOGGER("Foo: " << "Bar!: " << 42);
}
```

This outputs:

> Foo: Bar!: 42

I would like to have a similar interface for an ordinary C++ function. Sort of like this (does not compile, is not valid C++ code):

```c++
// has:
//    - insert( std::ostringstream & str ) function for obtaining content of a std::ostringstream
//    - formatting functions
//    - print( std::ostream & str ) function
class logger_class;

logger_class logger_function( some_magic_type varName ){
    std::ostringstream & str = varName;
    logger_class log;
    log.insert( str );
    return log;
}

int main(){
    logger_class log = logger_function("Foo: " << "Bar!: " << 42);
    log.format( some_formatting_options );
    log.print( std::cout );
}
```

Which would allow to format the output prior to actually sending it to *std::cout*.

**Edit:** C++11 and boost solutions are allowed as well.

Comment: Are you looking for overloaded versions of the <<-operator (a replacement for std::out or std::err named logger?)

Comment: @urzeit Sort-of. I want to ensure that the logger can assume that the input he was passed just now is the full message. Let me give you an example: One formatting option is colouring, which (assuming an ANSI terminal) consists of enclosing the content by two delimiters. By using the macro solution this can be done easily by adding the delimiters before and after streaming the log message into the output stream (because the whole log message is contained in the macro's argument).

Comment: I want the function to return the logger object because this allows to set the formatting options by using method chaining, i.e.: `logger_function("Foo" << 42).log_level( 500 ).color( RED ).weight( BOLD ).end_line();`

Comment: You seem to be mixing two styles: method chaining and streaming (which would normally use manipulators instead of method calls). Eg, would this syntax work: `log() << "Foo" << 42 << log_level(500) << log_color(RED) << log_weight(BOLD) << endl;` ?

Comment: Yes, I do mix streaming and method chaining. I know. Streaming is done to **form the argument** of a function, which returns an object (holding the data that was combined by using streaming). This object can be **configured** using method chaining and eventually will write its stored (and now formatted) data to an actual outstream.

Comment: In order to achieve colouring using streaming only one would need to write: `log() << log_level( 500 ) << log_color(RED) << log_weight(BOLD) << "Foo" << 42 << finish_color() << finish_weight() << std::endl;` because ANSI colouring requires a _start colouring_ and an _end colouring_ sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Using C++11, you could use variadic templates:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostringstream & fill_stream(std::ostringstream & str, T&& t)
{
    return (str << std::forward<T>(t));
}

template <typename T, typename... Vs>
std::ostringstream & fill_stream(std::ostringstream & str, T&& t, Vs&&... vs)
{
    str << std::forward<T>(t);
    return fill_stream(std::forward<Vs>(vs)...);
}

template <typename... Ts>
logger_class logger_function( Ts&&... vars ){
    std::ostringstream & str;

    if (!fill_stream(str, std::forward<Ts>(vars)...))
    {
        //Error!
    }

    logger_class log;
    log.insert( str );
    return log;
}
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    logger_class log = logger_function("Foo: ", "Bar!: ", 42);
    log.format( some_formatting_options );
    log.print( std::cout );
}
```

If you want to avoid creating the string stream immediately, you could create a templated class that stores its arguments in a tuple.

```
template <typename... Ts>
logger_class<Ts&&...> logger_function( Ts&&... vars ){
    // logger_class should probably store its arguments as a tuple
    logger_class<Ts&&...> log ( std::forward<Ts>(vars)... );
    return log;
}

int main()
{
    auto log = logger_function("Foo: ", "Bar!: ", 42);
    log.format( some_formatting_options );
    log.print( std::cout );
}
```